# I want to divide a hyperspace into cubes.The cubes make a B+ tree ,how can I do it?

Tags: cube, b-tree

The hyperspace contains large amount of high dimensional points .

I tends to partition the space into cubes.

And the cubes composes a B+ tree. I've read much about B+ tree.

But I don't know how to number the cubes and  choose the max number of keys a node can

have,then I can efficiently .visit neighbor cube of a cube .

Can anybody give some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can re-imagine any n-dimensional array as a linear sequence by transforming it into a series of (n-1)-dimensional arrays.

Here's a simple example. Suppose we have a 2 x 2 array of objects:

```
a b
c d
```

Languages with array indices encourage you to think of it as a nested data structure, like this python code:

```
a, b, c, d = 'abcd'
data = { 0: { 0 : a, 1 : b },  1: { 0 : c, 1 : d } }
fetch = lambda x, y: data[y][x]
assert fetch(0, 1) == c
```

But you can also think of it as a flat array like this:

```
data2 = [ a, b, c, d ]
data2_width = 2
fetch2 = lambda x, y : data2[(y * data2_width + x)]
assert fetch2(0, 1) == c
```

The general idea is that you multiply by the length of the dimension to get the next row.

You can apply that idea recursively to any number of dimensions. So if your dimensions are tuvxyz, and the lengths are TUVWXYZ, then for any object, you just take its coordinates and calculate { (t * T * u * U * v * V * w * W * x * X * y * Y) + z }.

To pick a neighbor along the u dimension, you add or subtract 1 from u and run the calculation again.